# can't install karma in node.js

Tags: node.js, npm

Here's what I get:

```
H:\>npm install -g karma npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma 
npm ERR! Error: connect ETIMEDOUT npm ERR!
     at errnoException (net.js:878:11) npm ERR!
     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:869:19) 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at: npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues> npm ERR! or email it to: npm ERR!
     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\no ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "karma" 
npm ERR! cwd H:\ 
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.3 
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.17 
npm ERR! syscall connect npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT 
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in: 
npm ERR!     H:\npm-debug.log npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I'm total newbie with node.js. I'm only using it because I want to use Karma for unit testing my angularjs application.

Any idea what's going on ?

EDIT log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   'karma' ]
2 info using npm@1.2.17
3 info using node@v0.10.3
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose read json C:\Users\berthelots\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
6 verbose read json C:\Users\berthelots\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
7 verbose cache add [ 'karma', null ]
8 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="karma" args=["karma",null]
9 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
9 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
9 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
9 verbose parsed url   host: null,
9 verbose parsed url   port: null,
9 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
9 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
9 verbose parsed url   search: null,
9 verbose parsed url   query: null,
9 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'karma',
9 verbose parsed url   path: 'karma',
9 verbose parsed url   href: 'karma' }
10 silly lockFile 512423cb-karma karma
11 verbose lock karma C:\Users\berthelots\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\512423cb-karma.lock
12 silly lockFile 512423cb-karma karma
13 silly lockFile 512423cb-karma karma
14 verbose addNamed [ 'karma', '' ]
15 verbose addNamed [ null, '' ]
16 silly lockFile cd7961bb-karma karma@
17 verbose lock karma@ C:\Users\berthelots\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\cd7961bb-karma.lock
18 silly addNameRange { name: 'karma', range: '', hasData: false }
19 verbose url raw karma
20 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './karma' ]
21 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
22 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 13:28:17
23 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
24 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
25 info trying registry request attempt 2 at 13:28:48
26 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
27 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
28 info trying registry request attempt 3 at 13:30:09
29 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/karma
30 silly lockFile cd7961bb-karma karma@
31 silly lockFile cd7961bb-karma karma@
32 error Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
32 error     at errnoException (net.js:878:11)
32 error     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:869:19)
33 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
33 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
33 error or email it to:
33 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
34 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
35 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "karma"
36 error cwd H:\
37 error node -v v0.10.3
38 error npm -v 1.2.17
39 error syscall connect
40 error code ETIMEDOUT
41 error errno ETIMEDOUT
42 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Have you looked into the log files. What does it say? Does this happen if you repeat the command? Do you have write access to the folder whre node modules are installed?

Comment: i've tried multiple times, always the same problem. I've updated node.js to latest version, and I do have write access to the C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules folder

Comment: From what I can see this is an issue with the network. Does the npm.log tell you more. It there: `H:\npm-debug.log`

Comment: Also a quick google search, brought this up: https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3130

Comment: @TheHipp, yes there was a log: see edited post

Comment: ha yes, it seems to be a proxy issue, I'll fix that with config set

Comment: you are: 1) behind a proxy, 2) some how you npm does not accept the certificate from the registry server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference:

Check if your proxy allows the connection. Otherwise see [this issue](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3130) how to set a proxy for npm.

Comment: also, this link explains clearly how to do it: http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy